# How do I get IntelliJ's Download Sources to work?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Sometimes it's nice to be able to look at the sources for libraries you are using. And often, IntelliJ will just show those to you without having to do anything. However, sometimes, you just get stubs generated by a decompiler. In those cases, IntelliJ will pop up a bar with options like "Decompile to Java" and "Download Sources". Clicking Download Sources will actually download a `*-sources.jar` file, but I've never actually seen it switch to displaying actual sources after that. Why is that? Can I do something to make this feature work?

I'll add an example. I have the `LazyGridIntervalContent` class from (compose) `foundation-desktop:1.5.1` open. It shows a bunch of method stubs, all ending with `/* compiled code */`. When I click "Download Sources", I get a Gradle window, which outputs

```
> Task :app:DownloadSources
Attempt to download sources from MavenRepo
Sources were downloaded to C:\Users\Jorn\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.compose.foundation\foundation-desktop\1.5.1\71341e4cdac6188a1f6917fc7386d6ee66a6790\foundation-desktop-1.5.1-sources.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
15:30:06: Execution finished ':app:DownloadSources  -Dorg.gradle.configuration-cache=false -Dorg.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=false'.
```

I can see the file is there on my file system. I can also manually select it using "Choose Sources...", but that doesn't change anything. No actual source code appears.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18292 might be related. Or perhaps create another KTIJ issue, as this problem keeps reappearing and they really ought to fix it once and for all.

Comment: What version of IDEA you are using? Both current Stable and EAP versions seem to work with dependencies' sources as intended.

Comment: @romanv-jb I see what Jorn describes in the latest version 2023.2.3 and previous versions. It doesn't happen all the time, but happens far too often. For example, I click on a Kotest function, and it shows the decompiled class even though I've download the sources already. But on another day, it might show me the sources.

Comment: @romanv-jb I'm on the latest stable, 2023.2.3. From the Youtrack link, maybe this only happens with Multiplatform projects?

Comment: In this case it definitely makes sense to submit a YouTrack Issue or a Support Ticket to have this thoroughly investigated and resolved.